# What are the most flexible language for computer vision?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

During developing algorithm I need a lot of well known descriptos, such as SURF, HOG, Hessian, combined with classifiers (SVM).
Also I would need to do a lot of tweaking of these algorithms (not just hyperparameters changing).
As far as I know Matlab computer vision toolbox is not very good for all of these.

Which language or software has more open source libraries and provides best flexibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV is fast and contains everything you need, I would prefer to use it in python (it has an interface for python)

and then use **Scikit-learn** for machine-learning, which is a simpler yet powerful library in python. with a very active open-source community

Since you are familiar with Matlab, **NumPy** and **matplotlib** should be easier to learn, they have a lot of methods and syntax in common. *I did matlab before python too and found easier to grasp NumPy*

**Scipy, Pandas, Ipython-Notebook** are other libraries that can be easily used and are shipped with Anaconda distribution of python. Scikitlearn is also shipped with Anaconda.

just get the Anaconda distribution from link below and you're ready to work, everything is well managed in anaconda, you don't even need to worry about package management and dependency issues.

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 3):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) - Open-source C++ library, with interface to Python and Java.

Sounds like it has everything you need.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like OpenCV is what I need.